# How do I add a field value to existing artifacts in WSO2 GREG?

Tags: registry, repository, wso2

I would like to update the schema artifact type shipped with WSO2 GREG (Governance Registry) 4.5.3 with some additional fields. This is my new Artifact Source:

```
<artifactType type="application/x-xsd+xml" fileExtension="xsd" shortName="schema" singularLabel="Schema" pluralLabel="Schemas" hasNamespace="true" iconSet="29">
<content href="../generic/schema_view_ajaxprocessor.jsp?hideStandardView=true">
    <field >
     <name>Gender</name>
     <values>
      <value>male</value>
      <value>female</value>
     </values>
</field>
```

It works when adding a new schema artifact, but when editing existing schema artifacts (existing before this update) I don't have the option to select a value for the field "Gender".

Which options do I have to set the "Gender" values for my already imported schemas?

Answer (score 1):

In WSO2 Governance Registry schemas, policies, wadls, swaggers and wsdl's are content type RXTs which are viewed differently than normal artifacts so it is not possible to define a custom field for schema artifact as you have tried. in other artifact types(metadata type) shipped with WSO2 GREG such as api or service you can create additional fields and the changes will also be reflected in existing artifacts.

However in your case you can achieve this by associations. [Management console associations](https://docs.wso2.com/display/Governance510/Managing+Dependencies+and+Associations) and New [Governance Center associations](https://docs.wso2.com/display/Governance510/Adding+Associations+in+the+Publisher).

To create your own RXTs please find [this article](http://sencs.blogspot.com/2016/03/how-to-create-new-artifacts-type-in.html).

You can add additional fields by inserting a new table element under the content element as given below or by adding a field element to a existing table element

```
  <table name="Overview">
   <field type="text" required="true" readonly="true">
      <name>Name</name>
   </field>
   <field type="text" required="true" readonly="true">
      <name>Address</name>
   </field>
   <field type="options" readonly="true">
      <name label="Sex">Sex</name>
      <values>
         <value>male</value>
         <value>female</value>
      </values>
   </field>
  </table>
```